# Suppress volume number in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I remove the volume and issue number for all entries in my bibliography, as in

> C Wetterich. “Variable gravity universe”. Physical Review D <strike>89.2</strike>
>   (2014), p. 024005. arXiv:1308.1019v2.

Comment: You can do `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{volume}\clearfield{issue}}`. But that will delete all `volume` and `number` fields. Do you want to delete the fields only for this entry, for all `@article`s, ...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{volume}%
  \clearfield{number}}
```

you will delete `volume` and `number` for all entries in the bibliography.

Comment: Where in the document do you put this?

Comment: @ShepBryan In the preamble (after you loaded `biblatex`). But note that this is a `biblatex` answer it will not work if you are using classical BibTeX (with `\bibliography` in the document body and `\bibliographystyle`).